# Dynamically resize objects into equal columns using css

Tags: html, css, dynamic, css-float

I am trying to create a layout that automatically re-sizes the widths of of container to fit the remaining space of the parent. Sort of like this:

[image: Quick design in photoshop]

The data will load in from a Database but I wasn't sure how possible this is to do. I tried to recreate this layout, before loading objects from the database but cant work out how to make the last container on each line to fill the remaining space.

CSS:

```
ul,li{
    list-style:none;
}
ul{
    width:1000px;
    display:block;
    height:auto;
}
li{
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    background:red;
    height:150px;
    display:block;
}
```

Simple loop:

```
for($x = 0; $x < 20; $x++){
    echo '<li style="width:'.rand(150,400).'px"></li>';
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

If anyone could explain a way that I could dynamically resize the last container of each line to make it flush I would greatly appreciate it. But I don't want to use a template or a plugin as I would rather learn how to build it from scratch.

Comment: Maybe use bootstrap? Would be easier I think.

Comment: It looks like you need to use *[masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html)* grid layout. Also have a look at *[isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)* and *[salvattore](http://salvattore.com/)*

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is defiantly your best shot here. Bootstrap is a grid layout using divs and used right is fully responsive.

So for example if you wanted a wider column and two smaller columns you could do:

```
<div class="row"><!--always size of 12 in bootstrap-->
  <div class="col-md-6">
   wider column content in here
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
   smaller first column content in here
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
   smaller second column content in here
  </div>
</div><!--end row div-->
```

So if we take it mathematically: the row is always taking its own size as 12, so our col-md-6 will always dynamically scale to 50% of the rows width (6 is 50 % of 12) and a our two smaller columns will always dynamically scale to 25% of the row width (3 is 25% of 12).

Here is a great tool for generating snippets of bootstrap html code

[Layitout.com](http://www.layoutit.com/)

And here you can find all the bootstrap resources you might need

[GetBootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Grabbing their CSS is the best place to start, you can link it straight from their site in a CSS href.

Have fun.